# java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=&sensor=true in android

Tags: android

I am trying to geocode the address using lat long with Google API URL as follows.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters

But getting the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=17.3575578,78.4609299&sensor=true
```

Comment: Pls post the codes to your current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to https. 
You no longer need the sensor. 
You can get a server API key and include it as well. Don't forget to enable in the console. This gets you 2,500 messages a day.
I had the same error today and this fixed it.
Strange http still works in a browser.